# Is there a way to install Visual Studio Community 2019 in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: software-installation, 19.10, visual-studio-code

Can I install **Visual Studio Community 2019** (not Visual Studio Code)? I don't care if is via Terminal, Ubuntu Software or through download from the website. If is possible, please tell me how. If is not possible, please tell me a replacement for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to install Visual studio Community on Ubuntu. But you can try and find alternative on [Alternative for Visual Studio](https://alternativeto.net/software/visual-studio/?platform=linux)
maybe it will help. It would be better next time if you would say which programming language you will use and for what.